Add a outlook calendar event to a single's user calendar with options to accept/decline using Graph API
I have been trying to programmatically add an event to a Outlook user's calendar, and also providing the options to accept/decline/maybe. After the event has been created, on checking I see that there are no options to accept/decline. These options only show up after inviting another user. But for my use case I need this to be done for a single user as attendee.
I have tried putting the user email into the attendees field while sending the event creation request but it is not working. My payload is set as below:
{
  subject: 'event_1',
  body: { content: undefined },
  start: { dateTime: '2024-07-22T08:00:00Z', timeZone: 'UTC' },
  end: { dateTime: '2024-07-22T208:30:00Z', timeZone: 'UTC' },
  attendees: [
    {
      emailAddress: {
        address: 'attendee@email.com',
        name: 'attendee@email.com'
      },
      type: 'required'
    }
  ],
  isOrganizer: false,
  isOnlineMeeting: false,
}


After this as you can see it does not provide any response options.
I have already searched all the questions asked on various sites but cannot find a matching query like mine. Suggest me some ways through which I can achieve this as I have already done it for Google calendar.
